# Apache virtual hosts configuration for MAMP results in new sites going to the same folder

Tags: htaccess, apache, virtualhost, mamp

I have MAMP installed in my mac. Why is it that every time I create a new site, they all go to the same folder? Here is my */etc/hosts* file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost.funstuff
127.0.0.1   localhost.mysite
127.0.0.1   localhost.oldmysite
```

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888


############ FUN STUFF PAGE##############
<VirtualHost localhost.funstuff:8888>
  ServerName localhost.funstuff
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/funstuff"
 ServerAlias www.localhost.funstuff

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost localhost.mysite:8888>
  ServerName localhost.mysite
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite"
 ServerAlias www.localhost.mysite

</VirtualHost>

#### oldmysite ####
<VirtualHost localhost.oldmysite:8888>
  ServerName localhost.oldmysite
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/oldmysite/sites/oldmysite"
 ServerAlias www.localhost.oldmysite

</VirtualHost>
```

I've restarted the MAMP server and when I type: `http://localhost.funstuff:8888/`, `http://localhost.oldmysite:8888` or `http://localhost.mysite:8888`, it all goes to the fun stuff folder.

Comment: Using a Mac for 'normal' use is fine but please don't use it as a web server :C

Comment: its for local...

Comment: How are you resolving `localhost.mysite` to 127.0.0.1?   Did you add it to */etc/hosts*?

Answer (score 2):

Apache doesn't recommend using domains in the `<VirtualHost>` declaration, I have found from experience that you will have far less trouble using an asterisk here (`*`) and just let the domain be matched against the `ServerName` value.

Also, the first virtual host site behaves as a default for whenever the name does not exactly match one of the defined virtual hosts. Therefore I would recommend if you do not want the fun stuff page to be your default site, try adding a new default VirtualHost and corresponding blank page website to your *httpd.conf* file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888

# Default Virtual Host Site - Blank
<VirtualHost *.8888>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/default
</VirtualHost>

# Fun Stuff Page
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 ServerName localhost.funstuff
 ServerAlias www.localhost.funstuff
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/funstuff
</VirtualHost>

# My Site    
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 ServerName localhost.mysite
 ServerAlias www.localhost.mysite
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite
</VirtualHost>

# My Old Site
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 ServerName localhost.oldmysite
 ServerAlias www.localhost.oldmysite
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/oldmysite/sites/oldmysite
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My setup had only one <VirtualHost> with a domain in it and every other site was redirecting to it. This fixed the issue. Thanx a bunch!